# How to prevent UIAlertController being dismissed when clicked background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller

[image]

I want the UIAlert not to be dismissed when clicked to the background.
I have attached the snapshot.

Comment: the bounced `UIAlert` is which one? can you post the code ?

Comment: your question is good, you dont want to dismiss the uialertcontroller if user clicked on background or else

Comment: Have you used custom alert controller?

Answer (score 0):

**I don't think alert hide when you clicked on background.**

```
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController
                              alertControllerWithTitle:@"My Title"
                              message:@"Enter User Credentials"
                              preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```